# Python Pickling EOF issue

Tags: python, save, pickle, try-except, eoferror

I am attempting to load user points from a pickle file with the code below.

```
import pickle
filehandle = True
try:
    pickle_file = open("points.mvm", 'r')
except:
    filehandle = False
if filehandle:
    points = pickle.load(pickle_file)
    pickle_file.close()
else:
    points = 0
```

However, it raises an `EOFerror`. The file is definitely there and it appears to have content as well.

Comment: Pickle uses 'wb' and 'rb'

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

```
import pickle

points = 0

try:
    with open('points.mvm', 'rb') as pickle_file:
        points = pickle.load(pickle_file)
except IOError:
    pass

print points

points += 1

with open('points.mvm', 'wb') as pickle_file:
    pickle.dump(points, pickle_file)
```

Note, that if you still have the `points.mvm` file in your directory, you'll need to delete it as it is likely corrupt (i.e. not binary), and will give you the `EOFError`.

Comment: When I copy-and-pasted the code, it raised a `SyntaxError` on the first open() function. What is happening?